# How do I connect two monitors and a 42" LED TV screen to an AMD Radeon HD 6700 video card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have (2) Asus 27" monitors and (1) Hisence 42" LED TV screen.

Is it possible to have all three connected to an AMD Radeon HD 6700 video card on my computer as one whole desktop?

Comment: I'm almost sure you can't. This is an old graphics card that only has 2 points of performance on Video Card Benchmark. I think it can only support 1 display output, MAYBE 2 if you're lucky. You can always use adapters on its free ports to get a duplicated on more than one screen, though, I guess. But who knows. Googling "Radeon HD 6700 supported displays" might teach you otherwise, dunno. Too lazy to search.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card would need more than one VGA/HDMI/older connector to do multi-monitors.  This is what a VGA cable looks like:

[image: Photo of a VGA plug]

This is what an HDMI cable connector looks like:

[image: Photo of two HDMI plugs]

Once you've got the monitors both connected with either a VGA + HDMI or VGA + VGA or HDMI + HDMI (all demanding on what slots your graphics card has) you can right click on your desktop, and select "Screen Resolution" on windows 7. On XP you go into display and look for "Screen Resolution" or something like that. From the resolution window, you can set up displays on 'extend' mode (which is having two desktops) or 'duplicate' (it...duplicates the two displays)

Just look on the back of your case for the connectors.